# ERC20 Transfer Event error or intended?

Tags: web3js, events, testrpc, logs, erc-20

I'm trying to get an Event "Transfer" for the ERC20 Token with web3 function getTransactionReceipt

`event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)`

You can see the term **indexed**, this is causing me a strange behaviour.

[This Transfer transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54eda187e51c0a30c3d0e4d9cb846744c11c010e7bc4b2ee2193d58ed8d7f521#eventlog)

It's decoded:

- topics[0] = methodID
- topics[1] = from
- topics[2] = to
- data = value

I say that this is strange, because if the term **"indexed"** is not present, the event params are in a single string "**data**" , for example in the Multisig used by Golem.

The method submitTransaction triggers two events:

`event Confirmation(address sender, bytes32 transactionHash);
event Submission(bytes32 transactionHash);`

You can see both events [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ea172d9bacc6f9bb49877fb57f9d29f255b2da9f6cd0e1047db509698efad1d#eventlog)

First one is the confirmation:

- topic[0] = methodID
- data = sender + transactionHash concatenated

Second one is the submission event:

- topic[0] = methodID
- data = transactionHash

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, in [the solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html?highlight=indexed#modifiers) is specified that event params named indexed are stored in the topics.

I consider, it makes the decode more complex without need, it could be both in topics and data, but it's ok, I'll do a function to decode it.